# Error when \% is included in a sectioning command

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, sweave, xelatex

When I try to input a `\%` in a `\subsection`'s title and `Compile pdf`, I get the following error:

`File ended while scanning use of \@@BOOKMARK.`

How should I do it?

**EDIT**

Here is a reproducible example. The file is encoded in UTF-8 format.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}


\setmainfont[Scale=1.0]{Times New Roman} 
\setsansfont{Times New Roman}


\begin{document}

\section{Μέσες τιμές και 95\% Διαστήματα Εμπιστοσύνης}

\subsection{a \% b cd}

<<>>=
1+1
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: @RicardoSaporta why `\\%`? LaTeX is not R :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perhaps a configuration problem of `hyperref`. I do not have `Times New Roman`, but I succeeded with `xelatex` (TeXLive 2012, Ubuntu 13.04) in RStudio (v0.98.312) and `knitr` using the configuration below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\usepackage[unicode=true,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\begin{document}


\section{Μέσες τιμές και 95\% Διαστήματα Εμπιστοσύνης}

\subsection{a \% b cd}

<<>>=
1+1
@

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: percent in subsection title]

The document is UTF8 encoded. You probably need to tell `hyperref` the `unicode` option.

Comment: Thank you. It works even without xunicode. Do you think I should keep it?

Comment: @GeorgeDontas I'm not really a XeTeX expert, so I think you can go without xunicode if it works anyway